# Can I run a .NET 2 application below a .NET 4 website with multipleSiteBindingsEnabled

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I have a website with an app pool running .NET 4 on IIS 7 and it has the following setting in system.ServiceModel in the Web.config:

```
serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
```

The problem I have is that I want to be able to run an application below this using a .NET 2 app pool. When I try this the app complains that it has an unknown attribute for multipleSiteBindingsEnabled. I can't see a way to hide this .NET 4 attribute in the Web.config of the .NET 2 application. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the different versions of .net use different aspnet_isapi.dll to do there work and so are incomparable with each other.

All I can think of which might work is to put your .Net 2 application in its own virtual directory in IIS and set it with the right .Net version and on a different app pool. Try placing the virtual directory in a different location on the file system from the main site.

Even this might not work though. At which point you would need to place the .Net 2 application on its own sub domain of the master website.

Comment: It is set up as a virtual directory and is using a different app pool (you can't have one app pool running different frameworks). Placing the app somewhere else on the file system will not stop Web.config inheritance. Mapping it as another website using a subdomain is not an option - I need to keep it in the current location as it is referenced like this by other sites.

Comment: Ah I thought that might be the case, but didnt have time to test it, which means the only way will be a separate sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your .NET 4 application you should try to use:

```
  <location path="Net2VirtualFolderName">
      <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
    <!-- custom config -->
      </system.web>
  </location>
```